# how to install pre-finished hardwood floors?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor

I have pulled up the carpet in my bedroom and got down to the plywood subfloor.

Do I have to prepare the plywood or lay anything down prior to placing the lengths of 3/4" oak flooring down (and nailing it of course)?

I want to make 100% sure the floor will not make noise at all, because this is a problem in other areas of the house. Since i am redoing the floors I want them perfectly quiet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes indeed,  prep is required and very important. First step is to renail or screw down the plywood subfloor. If you have a pneumatic frame nailer, you can use 2 1/2 inch **threaded**, ring nails (never use common nails), or alternately use 1 5/8 inch drywall screws. Install your nails or screws every 8 to 10 inches apart along each joist line with special attention to seams of the plywood. The importance of securing the subfloor well cannot be understated. The major cause of squeaky floors is drying or aging wood loosening around the nails, allowing them to move.

The second step is to lay a layer of building felt or rosin paper between the subfloor and new hardwood. Simply roll it out and staple it enough to hold it in place. This will assure that there is no wood on wood contact which can also result in squeaks.